# JCR JSP taglib implementation

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, jcr

I'm looking for jsp taglib implementation for jcr. I need something for access to jcr Node's and Node's properties in xpath style.

Could anybody recommend me something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Apache Sling, Hippo's HST and Magnolia could be a step in your direction. AFAIK there is no single jsp taglib library for JCR repositories, but it should not be that hard to create though if you have some time. 
All three projects allow you to use different view layers that include JSP, Freemarker and others. I'm not all that familiar with Magnolia, but Hippo's view layer is MVC, pure Java/Spring based and uses JSP's for the default rendering. They also have a quite decent [getting started tutorial](https://www.onehippo.org/7_8/trails/developer-trail/hippo-baby-steps).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something like this and I think that [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/site/index.html) is really the best you can get. There's really not much of view layer libraries for JCR repositories, jsp taglib especially.

Maybe Spring Surf could possibly help you.

If I were you, I'd check out the source code of some CMS and look at their view layer, like Magnolia or Hippo, which has a very nice Spring MVC view layer implementation called HIPPO SITE TOOLKIT.

I would personally never do a view layer for my repository by myself. It depends what kind of repository is that. For instance it is quite hard to implement UI for document store, without tons of Javacsript it won't be much useful. It that case I would decided on some existing CMS, based on what JCR implementation I use. Magnolia supports both Jackrabbit and Modeshape. Hippo CMS only Jackrabbit